# Color filenames according to $LS_COLORS in vim

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I'm writing a simple vim syntax file for random note takings for work.

I would like to color filenames according to $LS_COLORS. I can prefix a filename in the notes file with something random, like '·', to make it easier for vim to tell "oh boy, there's a filename coming up!". But how would I go about implementing the actual coloring accoring to the environment variable $LS_COLORS?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: You would probably have to parse LS_COLORS to define your highlight groups

Comment: I wonder if something like the [AnsiEsc.vim](https://github.com/vim-scripts/AnsiEsc.vim) plug-in (or a similar one that parses ANSI séquences for colors would help with these... There's of course still the logic of detecting file types, so that's probably not enough, but maybe could help with that part of it?